# Warning message within R function seems to make the function not work?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

Using the syuzhet package in R, the following works but returns a warning message:

```
object <- get_text_as_string("path/name.txt")
```

When I put this in a function, it returns the same warning error but does NOT change the value of object:

```
gen <- function(file){
object <- get_text_as_string(file)
}

gen("path/name.txt")
```

This is the warning message, if it matters:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(path_to_file) :
  incomplete final line found on 'path/name.txt'
```

...but again, I get that from get_text_as_string() when used outside of the function, but it DOES change the value of object.

Anyone have any advice?  There must be something I don't understand about functions?

(I've looked for similar questions/answers, if I've missed the right one I'd be happy to just be directed there.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the warning. Objects assigned inside a function are local to that function and not available outside of it. A function can `return` a single object that can be assigned. If you want to update the value of `object` by assigning the result of `gen("path/name.txt")`, you would write `object <- gen("path/name.txt")`, using the `<-` assignment operator.

Comment: Just like if I run `mean(1:10)` no object is created with the result 5.5. If I want to keep the result around I use `my_var <- mean(1:10)`. This is good! Imagine if you needed to know what object name was used inside the `mean()` function? Imagine if you wanted to use the `mean()` function more than once and give the result different names!

Comment: alright, thanks.  i simplified this for the sake of asking the question, and perhaps shouldn't be using a function for what i'm doing.